# React Updating Nested State Object deletes other values

Tags: reactjs

I have read and tried many other variations of this issue from here but none seem to work.When I update the nested **login** object below using the DropDown it clears out all the other values entered into the Login object. 
As a result you have to run the dropdown first, then enter the other values in. This is not a good solution.

```
this.state = {
  login: {
    id: 0,
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    business: "",
    dateIn: 0,
    dateOut: 0,
    staffName: ""
  },
  dropdownOpen: false,
  saveVisitor: false,
  dropDownValue: "",
  inputBoxEnabled: false
};
```

Here is my method.

```
//passes the value from the dropdownbox to the staffNames property
changeDropDownValue(e) {
  const newValue = e.currentTarget.textContent; // e.target.value;

  //The idea is to create a dummy object perform operations on it and then replace the component's state with the updated object
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react

  var login = { ... this.state.login }
  login.staffName = newValue;
  this.setState({login})

  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    inputBoxEnabled: true,
    dropDownValue: newValue
  });
}
```

Anyone got an answer? Nested objects seem to be very problematic, but necessary when you sending the data to a db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do twice this.setState in a row like this, because setState is asynchronous. **this.state** value in the second is not yet updated.

instead try :

```
var login = { ... this.state.login, staffName: newValue }

this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  login,
  inputBoxEnabled: true,
  dropDownValue: newValue
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making two calls to `setState` and in the second one you pass the current `state` (but modified). `setState` updates the state asynchronously, the value of `state` in the second `setState` call does not have the new `login` values, and will be applied after the updated `login` values. This makes your changes in the first call to `setState` get lost.

Either:

- make a single call to `setState`
- only update explicitly the fields that have to change

You could also consider using `useState` from react hooks and segregate your state with those.